# Xcode: project entitlements

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 4, there is a Myproject.entitlements file.

What's it for?

In general, what are the "entitlements"? What are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to iCloud and push notifications (on iOS and Mac OS X) and the App Sandbox feature (in OS X only).

There is more information in [Entitlement Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH3-SW1). App Sandbox is documented in [App Sandbox Design Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html):

> An app that is not sandboxed has access to all user-accessible system
>   resources—including the built-in camera and microphone, network
>   sockets, printing, and most of the file system. If successfully
>   attacked by malicious code, such an app becomes a hostile agent with
>   wide-ranging potential to inflict harm.
>
> When you enable App Sandbox for your app, you remove all but a minimal
>   set of privileges and then deliberately restore them, one-by-one,
>   using entitlements. An **entitlement** is a key-value pair that identifies
>   a specific capability, such as the capability to open an outbound
>   network socket.

Comment: I saw that the same file appears for an iOS project. I knew that an iOS app has an own sandbox. Is a different thing or has something changed also for iOS apps? Do you know something about this?

Comment: I think the entitlements file also relates to push notifications and iCloud (on both iOS and Mac). See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Introduction/AboutEntitlements.html